# how to change sub-volumes' color in volume rendering with vtk？

Tags: vtk

I used vtk's volume rendering algorithm to render a volume data(eg. 500*500*100).If i want change certain sub-volumes'(eg 20*20*20) color,and how can i do that?
Any advice will be thankful!

I had tried some methods. Like vtkVolumePicker,vtkMultiBlockDataSet and so on. But all failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding in python you can consider using [vedo](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/tree/master/vedo/examples/volumetric), which allows you to go from/to numpy objects to vtkVolumes. Find examples [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/vedo/examples/volumetric/numpy2volume1.py).

Alternatively [pyvista](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista) can also help you depending on your needs.